# Set all menu items to be center of Bootstrap Menu Header

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Recently i have resized bootstrap's menu size. now problem is the text position of the menu items shows in a top of the menu bar.

I want to show menu items to center of the menu header. Menu items are already aligned in center position.

here is the my code : http://jsfiddle.net/y8v0rd9g

css:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about your request what you want.. Please give out an image of your requirement

Comment: "I want to show menu items to center of the menu header. Menu items are already aligned in center position." This sentence sounds like you do not have a problem after all. Please be more specific. It is also a good idea to include an image of what you have now, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: brand and collapse icon moved to be center. https://ibb.co/g1eXFQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use your browser's dev tools, you'd see that your links (`ul.nav`) are actually vertically center-aligned, but the list ends before the `nav` element does. That's because you're setting `min-height: 80px` on your nav. I'd recommend adding padding as well, but not the way @LKG did it. Instead, remove the min-height rule and add top and bottom padding only to your `.navbar`. That way the items remain center-aligned nicely. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8v0rd9g/6/) and updated code:

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/y8v0rd9g/3/

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider">
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider">
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider">
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Removed the min-height from **.nav**

Comment: Welcome @DineshKumar